# Modificar o user-agent no envio em uma requisição soap jax-rpc

Tags: java

Pessoal estou com um problema, tenho um projeto em java que envia requisições soap pelo formato jax-rpc. Sendo que agora eu tenho que modificar o user-agent que é enviado na requisição. Já  pesquisei no google e aqui(stackoverflow) e ainda não consegui mudar o user-agent da requisição soap. Alguem sabe como fazer ?

Comment: Como as requisições são feitas????

Comment: StreamingSenderState _state = _start(_handlerChain);
            InternalSOAPMessage _request = _state.getRequest();
            _request.setOperationCode(consultarConfiguracao_OPCODE);

Comment: Legal, jovem. Mas e o código?

Comment: Desculpe: O que acontece é que gerei o stub pelo plugin do netbeans : segue o link do metodo :
https://pastebin.com/a2NNEpUL